# How do you scan for specific directories, show this in echo, then give you an option to delete them?

Tags: batch, script

I wanted to know how to make a batch file search for directories, display the results and then give you a choice on deleting them or not.

I have searched and found out how to find the directories and display the results but I have no idea how to do the rest. I know this question has probably been asked a lot but I have spent a while the last few days trying to work it out.

so far I have this.

```
@echo off
cls
(
    for %%i in (C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (
        if exist "%%i:\" dir "%%i:\Test ID.txt" "%%i:\example.bat" /b /s /a-d
    )

)

pause > nul
```

I know this is quite basic and there are more efficient ways but I couldn't work out how to make it work. I did get another method to work as well as shown below

```
@acho off
cls
for %%i in (C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) DO @if exist "%%i:\testDocuments\testmy games\Test ID.txt" @echo %%i:\Documents\my games\
pause > nul
```

I got both of these and about three other examples off a webite but I only really understood these ones and got them to work. So basically both of these examples scan all drives for an ID file, or any file really as this is an example file.

The files are found correctly no matter which drives I place them on etc, but I don't know how to give the user a choice on deleting these directories but using the results of the found directories.

By the way the reason for the ID file is because the directories can have the same name but the contents are different so the ID file differetiates between them. Basically I have two varsions of a modded game and of course they will have the same directory names but the contents will be different. I know how to make inputs so people can choose as the Batch file is already quite large but the issue is merging with the either scripts above.

Sorry for the long post, I have tried looking and I can't work it out. By the way I am using the modded games for practising at batch scripting (mainly for fun or sorting odd tasks out), but I plan to use the scripts for other tasks.

Thanks.
note: I will be in bed soon so I may not reply for a while, as I am in the UK.